# How to get input from the terminal in Perl

Tags: perl

I am creating a simple chatterbot program like [ELIZA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA).

I'm taking questions from the terminal and sending reply with dialog, but my program takes only the first input and repeats.

For example, when I run my script the output may be something like this:

```
[Eliza]: Hi, I'm a psychotherapist. What is your name?
user Input: hello my name is adam.
[Eliza]: hello adam, how are you?
[Eliza]: your name is adam
[Eliza]: your name is adam
[Eliza]: your name is adam
[Eliza]: your name is adam
[Eliza]: your name is adam
```

And it repeats endlessly.

I don't know where I am doing wrong. How can I get my program to read the next line from the keyboard?

```
sub hello {
    print "[Eliza]: Hi, I'm a psychotherapist. What is your name? \n";
}


sub getPatientName {
    my ($reply) = @_;

    my @responses = ( "my name is", "i'm", "i am", "my name's" );

    foreach my $response ( @responses ) {

        if ( lc($reply) =~ /$response/ ) {
            return  "$'";
        }
    }

    return lc($reply);
}

sub makeQuestion {
    my ($patient) = @_;

    my %reflections = (
        "am"    =>   "are",
        "was"   =>   "were",
        "i"     =>   "you",
        "i'd"   =>   "you would",
        "i've"  =>   "you have",
        "i'll"  =>   "you will",
        "my"    =>   "your",
        "are"   =>   "am",
        "you've"=>   "I have",
        "you'll"=>   "I will",
        "your"  =>   "my",
        "yours" =>   "mine",
        "you"   =>   "me",
        "me"    =>   "you"
    );

    if ( $count == 0 ) {
        $patientName = getPatientName($patient);
        $count += 1;
        print "Hello $patientName , How are you? \n";
    }

    my @toBes = keys %reflections;

    foreach my $toBe (@toBes) {

        if ($patient =~/$toBe/) {
            $patient=~ s/$toBe/$reflections{$toBe}/i;
            print "$patient? \n";
        }
    }
}

sub eliza {

    hello();

    my $answer = <STDIN>;

    while ($answer) {
        chomp $answer;
        #remove . ! ;
        $answer =~ s/[.!,;]/ /;
        makeQuestion($answer);
    }
}

eliza();
```

Comment: It seems that all you need is `while (my $answer = <STDIN>)`.  What you have "loops over" `$answer` ... which is always true (so it keeps going), and which never again reads new input (so it keeps printing the same).

Comment: @zdim: I think "looping over" generally refers to a list, like a `for` statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `while` loop never reads input. The `$answer` got assigned `STDIN` before the loop and presumably has a string, that evaluates true in the `while` condition. The regex in the loop could in principle change `$answer` to false (by removing everything from it, turning it into an empty string)<sup>†</sup> but it doesn't fetch `STDIN`, nor does anything else in the loop body.

Thus not only is no new input assigned to `$answer`, but after the first iteration nothing at all changes in the loop.<sup>†</sup> So it keeps running forever, printing the question based on the same `$answer`.

You need

```
while (my $answer = <STDIN>) {
    chomp $answer;
    # ...
}
```

instead.

Every time the condition of `while (...)` is evaluated the new input is read via `<STDIN>` and is assigned to `$answer`.  Then each new question uses the new `$answer`. Note how a variable may be declared inside the `while` condition so to exist only inside the loop body (and in the condition after its declaration). This is a nice way to keep its scope restricted to where it is needed, inside the loop.

The filehandle read `<...>` returns `undef` when it gets `EOF` (or on error) and the loop terminates.  See [I/O Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators). A user at the terminal can normally achieve this by `Ctrl-d`.

---

<sup>†</sup>  For example, a regex like `$answer =~ s/.//;` removes a character each time it runs (except a newline, which `.` doesn't match without the `/s` modifier), so if applied repeatedly eventually `$answer` winds up being an empty string.  Of course, the regex in the question doesn't do that but it changes the string only the first time it runs on it.